# 301 Redirect with QUERY STRING

Tags: apache, .htaccess

I want to re-direct

```
http://www.mydomain.com/ladies-boots/?shoesize=43&calfwidth=K
```

To

```
http://www.mydomain.com/ladies-boots/#nogo&landing_sef_url=&producttype=
ladies-boots&shoesize=43&calfwidth=K
```

Currently i'm using the below code, however it's not working.

```
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} ^ladies-boots/?shoesize=([0-9]+)\&calfwidth=([A-Z])$ 
RewriteRule ^.*$ http://www.mydomain.com/ladies-boots/#nogo&landing_sef_url=&producttype=ladies-boots&%1 [R=301,L]
```

Please help me to this issues.

**This is my updated latest code,**

```
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} ^shoesize=([0-9]+)\&calfwidth=([A-Z])$ 
RewriteRule ^ladies-boots/$ http://www.mydomain.com/ladies-boots/#nogo&landing_sef_url=&producttype=ladies-boots&shoesize=%1&calfwidth=%2? [R=301,L]
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The QUERY_STRING parameter is just that; it doesn't contain the URI pathing info.

```
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} ^shoesize=([0-9]+)\&calfwidth=([A-Z])$ 
RewriteRule ^ladies-boots/$ $0#nogo&landing_sef_url=&producttype=ladies-boots&%1 [R=301,NE,L]
```

Remember to turn the engine on (`RewriteEngine On`) and set a base (`RewriteBase /`) first.  $0 pick up the whole match string, and the server and protocol default to the same so don't need to be specified.

Comment: Thanks a lot this is working fine.
There's another issues "#" tag is not redirecting properly.It's redirecting like this,
http://www.mydomain.com/ladies-boots/%23nogo&landing_sef_url=&producttype=ladies-boots&shoesize=43&calfwidth=K

Comment: Please see updated code and help me on this #tag issue, Thank you.

Comment: Yup, you need to add the NE flag.   Sorry about that.